How to reference HTML elements from ouside the App in Vue?
How to reference HTML elements outside of Vue's App tree?
For example if you have the following index.html:
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>    
    <div id="quote">
        This is it!
    </div>
</body>

how do you refer "quote" element inside the App component?

Edit (just to have a broader view over my problem) bellow I added the setup where it fails
import { describe, expect, test } from 'vitest'
import { mount, } from '@vue/test-utils'
import App from '@/App.vue'

describe('App', () => {

    test('Simply Render the Page', () => {
        
        const wrapper = mount(App) 
        
        expect(wrapper.html()).to.contain('This is it!') //fails
        console.log(document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML) //fails
    })
})

and here is the package.json
{
  "name": "outsidejob",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test:unit": "vitest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.4.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.5",
    "jsdom": "^24.0.0",
    "vite": "^5.1.6",
    "vitest": "^1.4.0"
  }
}


You generally don't. Make them to be inside app element. Consider explaining your case further if there's some problem with that

@EstusFlask Well...I generally agree with you but the problem is that a 3rd party library creates a  outside the app's  and I need to inspect that (outside)  for testing purposes (read test units)

Often third-party libs allow to provide them with an existing element to work with, this is the way they can be integrated into a framework. If this is not the case then just access with getElementById("quote"). But it's unclear how it ended up with ref="quote"

@EstusFlask Oh sorry, the ref was part of me trying to get a handle on it. I removed it from the code sample.

document.getElementByID('quote')

Also tested the getElementById() solution before, inside the test unit, and it didn't work. BUT when tested inside the App (in mounted() function for example) it's working. So the logical conclusion is that the test units, because they do not replicate the index.html setup, can not access the quote's  ...as it doesn't exist.

In unit tests you can manually add the element in beforeEach and cleanup in afterEach similar to how you add teleport targets.

@Alex It's unknown what's your testing environment. Jest and such provide fake dom that's capable of that, you can add mock elements to it to fit the expectations. Or abstract away all direct dom getElementById calls and mock the methods, which would be a cleaner way for unit tests

@EstusFlask I use vitest, test-utils and jsdom. Updated the question with these details.

@Alex I updated the post, this part is specific to testing

Direct DOM access isn't supposed to be used in Vue under normal circumstances, as long as this can be achieved in more idiomatic ways. This is achievable if <div id="quote"> can be moved inside a template of Vue applciation.
If <div id="quote"> were a container with no content, Vue components could be mounted to it as a separate app, or it could be used as a target for Vue teleport.
Considering that a developer isn't directly responsible for the creation of <div id="quote">, it can be referenced with regular DOM APIs inside Vue application, this is a justifiable use for them:
document.getElementById("quote")

In testing environment this requires to fulfill the expectations with mocked element:
let div;
beforeEach(() => {
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 'quote';
  
  document.body.appendChild(div); // remove in afterEach
  // or
  let { getElementById } = document;
  vi.spyOn(document, 'getElementById')
    .mockImplementation(id => id === 'quote' ? div : getElementById(id))
});

